# What's the alternative to my verbose IF statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am returned a string, `fruit` which could have many values, for example: `banana`, `apple`, `grapes`, `orange`, `mango` etc.

I want to output the value of this string, but I only want to display some of them. This has made my IF statement long & ugly:

```
 if ( fruit != 'apple' || fruit != 'grapes' || fruit != 'banana' ) {
      // display them
 }
```

How else could I write this? Would `.filter` work? Can I put the unwanted fruits into an array and say if `fruit` matches an array value, do nothing?

Comment: Asking JS to do `fruit != 'apple' || fruit != 'grapes'` would mean that the first condition is TRUE if `fruit == 'grapes'` and also TRUE if `fruit == 'apple'` for the second condition. Your statement has virtually no effect.

Comment: Good point. What's the correct way to lay it out?

Comment: @izolate That method requires `&&` instead of `||`, but the tidiest way of checking against multiple values is in my answer below

Comment: The correct would be using && between the elements since you want to display when it not apple AND not grapes etc. Like it is now it will display for grapes since it isn't apple and OR is satisfied with one being true.

Comment: This is asked once a week, searching a bit doesn't hurt.

Comment: And [Reduce multiple ORs in IF statement in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2630364/1331430)

Comment: And [IF Statement Multiple Answers - Same Result Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8711174/1331430) and a hundred more. All you have to do is flip the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var dontMatch = new Array('apple','grapes','banana');
if(dontMatch.indexOf(fruit) == -1)
{
    //fruit is none of the above
}
```

Comment: Array literals are preferred.

Comment: It should be noted that the `indexOf` method for arrays is a fairly new feature in JS, so if you have to support old IE, et al., you should have a workaround as well. The following page outlines a good workaround: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @SLaks Yea, I'd just changed my answer when I noticed your comment lol

Comment: Painless and succinct. Thanks!

Comment: @izolate Glad to have helped. Please remember to help future visitors of this question by marking the answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try a case statement?

```
switch(fruit) {
    case 'apple': // dont display
        break;
    case 'grapes': // dont display
        break;
    case 'banana': // dont display
        break;
    case 'orange': // display
        break;
    case 'mango': // display
        break;
}
```